# c# Nested categories (sub-categories) in the form control “property grid”

Tags: c#, controls, propertygrid

I'm new to C# and I've been trying to design my own program for a while now. I came a across a control named Property Grid, it suits me perfectly and aftering Googling, I managed to find how to split up the various properties into catagories using attritubtes.

But I cannot find any information on adding sub-catagories to another catagory. Can anyone shed light on this subject? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! I use a 3rd. party control that supports two levels of categories in its design-time Property Grid. A Property Grid, used at run-time, is interesting, since you can use it on controls, simple classes, components, etc., but you pay a "price" for use of "reflection" to translate between strings and "effects on objects." Matthew McDonald's book on Pro .Net 2.0 WinForms and Controls has good coverage of Property Grid, custom ui type editors, etc. in Chapters 13 and 26. I switched over to VS 2010 RC1, but have yet to investigate PropertyGrid in that context as a run-time control.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/PropertyGridValidation.aspx Property Grid - Dynamic List ComboBox, Validation, and More
By Dave Elliott 2008 article, updated in 2009 : the author is still responding to questions as of Feb. 2010. If you look at his source code example for use of a 'View TypeEditor in the public class ViewPersonCollection in a PropertyGrid: you can see he is able to achieve treeview-style nesting in a PropertyGrid down to three or more levels. Note : his source converted to VS 2010 RC1 FrameWork 3.5 with no problems other than having to manually set the start-up project.

Comment: Thank you, your reply is appreciated. I've found a solution - using the attribute [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))] on classes I wish to make expandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PropertyGrid control doesn't support "nested" categories. Is there something in particular that you're trying to do (e.g. another application that you've seem which implements the functionality that you're trying to achieve) and maybe we can steer you in the right direction...

Comment: The main reason for this is because of the sheer number of properties would probably make navigating the properties grid tiresome. For example: I have "Offset" with x, y ,z. I also have quite a few others propertys that would all strongly relate with each other.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, there's not much you can do about that. You might be able to do something with a custom type editor (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171839.aspx) perhaps...